# How to disable Nelmio UI in production?

Tags: symfony, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

Is there a way to turn off all of the Nelmio Swagger UI docs? In production I want the outside world to see nothing at the following URLs, but in dev they should display useful docs & sandbox as normal:

- http://ourserver.com/api/doc
- http://ourserver.com/api-docs
- http://ourserver.com/api-docs/*

Seems like there should be an easy switch for this in the Nelmio config, but I haven't found it. My company is using the Nelmio API Doc bundle in Symfony to develop APIs for a non-public API. The API server is exposed to the public, but we're not interested in publishing its usage to the world.

Comment: Enable the bundle only for dev environment: `if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) { new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@gp_sflover's comment got me on the right track, but there's more to it than just disabling NelmioApiDocBundle on prod in `AppKernel.php`. Configs & routes that refer to Nelmio will generate errors until you move them into dev-specific files. The following change in `app/AppKernel.php` was the first step:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        ...
        // new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle(), // <-- REMOVED FROM HERE
        new Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle(); // <-- ADDED HERE
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        ...
```

To eliminate the config errors, I had to move the following stuff out of `app/config/config.yml` and into `config_dev.yml`:

```
# nelmio Configuration
nelmio_api_doc:
    sandbox:
        enabled: true
    name: 'DLAP API Bridge'
    swagger:
        ...
    cache:
        enabled: false
```

Likewise, the following stuff came out of `app/config/routing.yml` and moved to `routing_dev.yml`:

```
NelmioApiDocBundle:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api/doc

nelmio_api_swagger:
    resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/swagger_routing.yml"
    resource: null
    prefix: /api-docs
```

Answer (score 3):

Now with symfony4 and flex you can install the bundle normally

```
composer require nelmio/api-doc-bundle
```

(So it won't be set as a `require-dev` depandency in your `composer.json`)

Now you change the setting in the `project/config/bundles.php` to:

```
Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle::class => ['dev' => true]
```

So you don't get errors (eg from annotations), but it wont be loaded from `Kernel.php`

Answer (score 2):

For disabling the Nelmio api-doc-bundle on specific environment, after some investigation, I ended up doing the following:

- only enable the bundle on your target environment, i.e. on `project/config/bundles.php` have:

```
Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle::class => ['dev' => true]
```

- put the config annotation on env specific (put `nelmio_api_doc.yaml` inside `./config/packages/dev/`)
- put the route file `nelmio_api_doc.yaml` inside `./config/routes/dev` (instead of being in the `./config/routes`), otherwise, if you call the route for another environment which doens't have the bundle loaded, instead of 404, you will see 500)

Answer (score 1):

not loading the bundle in config/bundles.php throws an exception in **Symfony 4.3** with **NelmioApiDocBundle Version 3**:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "nelmio_api_doc"
```

I ended up disabling the route for the api docs with a redirect in the environment, which needed to be disabled (prod):

```
#config/routes/prod/nelmio_api_doc.yaml
app.swagger:
    path: /api/doc.json
    methods: GET
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /
        permanent: true

app.swagger_ui:
    path: /api/doc
    methods: GET
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /
        permanent: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the sandbox using swagger UI config when dumping html file via the console.

```
$ php bin/console nelmio:apidoc:dump --format=html --html-config '{"assets_mode":"offline","server_url":"https://example.com","swagger_ui_config":{"supportedSubmitMethods":[]}}' > api.html
```

Docs:

https://symfony.com/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/current/commands.html

Swagger:

https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration